# Qual a diferença entre ID="" e NAME=""?

Tags: php, html

Eu comprei um dashboard da internet e ao me deparar com o código vi o seguinte:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control round" id=" " placeholder="Your Username" required>
```

Nos tutoriais da internet vi que preciso pegar o comando `name=""` para que possa referenciá-lo em outro arquivo.

Queria saber qual a diferenca do comando `NAME=" "` para `ID=""` pois aparentemente servem pra mesma função ou estou equivocado?

Está certo eu remover o `id=""` e colocar o `name=""`? Fiz essa alteração e comigo funcionou (validação de formulario na database) porém fiquei com dúvida, o `ID=""` serve pra que?

Comment: `name` você associa um nome para o elemento do `input` ou `form`. Quando enviado para o PHP, você usará o `name` para encontrar seu valor. Já o `id`, ele define a identificação naquele código para o navegador. É usado no Ajax ou no CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, como o nome mesmo já diz o `ID` é um "elemento" onde este deve ser único, ou seja, o nome que você colocar no ID de um elemento, não deve se repetir no código, pois gera conflitos. Já o `name` trabalha de forma diferente, o mesmo você pode utiliza-lo desde referenciar uma label de um form, até a parte que você percorre dados para envio ao Banco de Dados. Os "names" são os atributos onde você referencia no seu backend para pegar o valor dos inputs, estes quais você preenche as informações as quais deseja armazenar. Mais que isso ainda, os "names" podem ser transformados numa especie de "Array" quando colocado `[]`no final de sua decalaração; isto serve para formulários onde você pode ter campos que são clonados e terão o mesmo nome, como Produto, quantidade, preço etc.

Comment: entao estou fazendo validacao de formulario apenas, entao eu tirando o ID como estava e adicionando o name , nao havera problemas certo? apenas se posteriormente quiser trabalhar isso  com ajax ou css correto? como uso html e php nenhum problema certo?

Comment: Sim, a validação do Form você pega os dados através do Name dos objetos. Lembrando que você só consegue capturar o valor de input's quando é feito o submit do Form, se tentar pegar valores de DIV e afins, creio que apenas com AJAX e JQuery. Com o PHP, vamos supor que você tenha um Form de cadastro e precisa capturar o nome da pessoa, usando o ```$_POST['nome']``` ( pensando que esse é o name de seu input ), o valor do mesmo já é capturado. Recomenda-se usar o POST ao inves do GET para a maioria dos submits, o POST envia mais dados e é mais seguro, pois nao fornece informações pela URL da page.

Comment: muito obrigado se pudesse te dava pontos! kk obg